# How do I change the sorting method of files used by asterisk (*) in bash?

Tags: bash, files, date, sort

I am trying to run a command on all files in a directory starting with the file that has the earliest modification date and ending with the file with the latest.

I find the asterisk (`*`) to be useful for running a command on all files in a directory, in this way:

```
$ stat -x *
```

but that sorts the files alphabetically, is there any way to achieve the same function but starting with the file with the earliest modification date?

EDIT: I mean "earliest" in the human sense, the oldest file.

Comment: `stat -x *(om)` in ZSH (or `*(Om)` depending on whether "earliest" means the file with the lowest modification epoch or the the file most recently modified)

Comment: Are you interested in a wrapper function that `stat`s every file, loads an array, and then loops through the array?  Otherwise, see [zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442357/how-do-i-change-the-sorting-method-of-files-used-by-asterisk-in-bash#comment800772_442357)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming GNU tools, you'll have to do something like

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*ASD*' -printf '%T@\t%p\0' | 
  sort -z -k1.1n |
  while IFS=$'\t' read -rd '' mtime name; do
    # do something with the filename
    echo ">>>$name"
  done
```

The extra hoops are to handle any conceivable filename, such as those that contain newline characters.

To encapsulate that in a function, I'd write:

```
files_by_mtime () { 
    local pattern=$1
    local -n arr=$2
    arr=()
    while IFS=$'\t' read -rd '' mtime name; do
        arr+=("$name")
    done < <(
        find . -maxdepth 1 -name "$pattern" -printf '%T@\t%p\0' | sort -z -k1.1n
    )
}

files_by_mtime '*' myarr
for file in "${myarr[@]}"; do
    # do something with the filename
    echo ">>>$file"
done
```

Required bash verson 4.3+

Comment: I think you want `-mindepth 1` as well for the `find` command or else you'll get the current directory in the output if it happens to match the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

`ls -tr` will sort the files in the current directory by earliest mod time.

Comment: only this doesn't run `stat` on the files (and risks parsing ls for doing so)

Comment: @JeffSchaller: not sure I understand - the OP is asking for a way to run a command on a set of files sorted in a specific way: does `command $(ls -tr)` (assuming no problems with the length of the command line) not do that? what does `stat` have to do with it? I thought it was just an example.

Comment: Correct; `stat` was just the example command. Yes, `command $(ls -tr)` breaks with `touch "some file"`, for example.